# Simplify expressions given by sympy.sympify

Tags: python, sympy

sp.simplify doesn't seem to work when your expression is given by sp.sympify. How can I change that?

```
import sympy as sp

r = sp.Symbol('r', real = True)
f_str = 'sqrt(1/r**4)'

f1 = sp.sympify( f_str )
f2 = sp.sqrt(1/r**4)

for f in f1,f2:
    sp.pprint(sp.simplify(f))
```

which outputs

```
     ____
    ╱ 1  
   ╱  ──           # f1
  ╱    4 
╲╱    r  

1 
──                 # f2
 2
r
```

I was expecting that given a real value (r), a sympify expression could get simplified

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `r` in `f1` isn't the same as the `r` symbol you defined:

```
>>> f1.free_symbols == f2.free_symbols
False
```

In particular, this means that the assumption that `r` is real doesn't carry through, which is necessary for the simplification you want.

You can remedy this postmortem by substituting the `r` in `f1` with your `r` symbol:

```
>>> f1                # old r, no assumptions
sqrt(r**(-4))

>>> f1.subs("r", r)   # your r, with real assumption
r**(-2)
```

In general, you can specify [assumptions for string inputs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/guides/assumptions.html#applying-assumptions-to-string-inputs) at construction time by passing a dictionary mapping string symbols to your desired SymPy Symbols:

```
>>> f3 = sp.sympify(f_str, {"r": r})

>>> f3
r**(-2)

>>> f3.free_symbols == f2.free_symbols
True
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is correct but I want to note an alternative way that might be useful. The `sympify` function when given a string as input will pass that string to SymPy's `parse_expr` function. Actually if you are parsing strings then it is better to call `parse_expr` directly rather than using `sympify`. If you do use `parse_expr` directly then you can pass other options to control how the expression gets parsed including specifying which symbol objects to use for each symbol name appearing in the string.

```
In [4]: import sympy as sp
   ...: 
   ...: r = sp.Symbol('r', real = True)

In [5]: sp.parse_expr('sqrt(1/r**4)', {'r': r})
Out[5]: 
1 
──
 2
r 

In [6]: sp.parse_expr('sqrt(1/r**4)')
Out[6]: 
     ____
    ╱ 1  
   ╱  ── 
  ╱    4 
╲╱    r
```