# Sympy parsed expression is not evaluating correctly

Tags: python, expression, sympy

I'm following the [Sympy logical expression documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/logic.html), and have tested the following example, which seems to work well.

```py
>>> (x | y).subs({x: True, y: False})
True
```

When I replace the '(x | y)' expression, with an identical expression, but this time derived from the parse_expr function, the subs() method returns 'x', instead of 'True':

```py
>>> exp = parse_expr('(y | x)')
>>> print(exp)
x | y
>>> exp.subs({x: True, y: False})
x
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I don't know anything about Sympy, but it seems odd to me that `parse_expr('(y | x)')` would result in `x | y`.  Aren't those backwards from each other?

Comment: Can't reproduce. `parse_expr('(y | x)').subs({x: True, y: False})` evaluates to `True` for me.

Comment: @JohnGordon Sympy is a symbolic math library. It likes to simplify expressions to some normalized form, which usually involves sorting the arguments to commutative operators. In this case `'(y | x)'` is normalized to `x | y`.

Comment: Can you show us how you're defining `x` and `y`? If you added any assumptions to them, then it's possible that those variables aren't referencing the same symbols as the free variables in `exp`. What do `x in exp.free_symbols` and `y in exp.free_symbols` evaluate to?

Comment: Thanks @Brian61354270. I reinstalled Sympy using a different version of python (3.10), and I'm getting the expected result now, too.

Comment: In general, you need to be careful when equating symbols you construct yourself with symbols that are interpreted from stings. See also [Simplify expressions given by sympy.sympify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75593816/11082165)